# Replace value of one namespace attributes from many in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a input SOAP message which have multiple namespace attributes. I want to replace one attribute value from many attributes and keep other attributes same.

My input is

```
<abc:outerblock xmlns:abc="http://www.example1.com/" xmlns:abc2="www.example2.com" xmlns:abc4="http://www.example4.com" >
    <abc4:innerblock>
        <abc4:entry1>22</abc4:entry1>
        <abc4:entry2>xyz</abc4:entry2>
    </abc4:innerblock>
</abc:outerblock>
```

My output should look like this.

```
<abc:outerblock xmlns:abc="http://www.changed.com/" xmlns:abc2="www.example2.com" xmlns:abc4="http://www.example4.com" >
    <abc4:innerblock>
        <abc4:entry1>22</abc4:entry1>
        <abc4:entry2>xyz</abc4:entry2>
    </abc4:innerblock>
</abc:outerblock>
```

After trying many solutions on stackoverflow. I came up with this solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">

      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http://www.example1.com/']">

 <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace='http://www.changed.com/'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it produce result like this.

```
<abc:outerblock xmlns:abc="http://www.changed.com/">
   <abc4:innerblock xmlns:abc="http://www.example1.com/"
                    xmlns:abc2="www.example2.com"
                    xmlns:abc4="http://www.example4.com">
      <abc4:entry1>22</abc4:entry1>
      <abc4:entry2>xyz</abc4:entry2>
   </abc4:innerblock>
</abc:outerblock>
```

All tags are copied to child elements. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unuesed namespace declarations shouldn't actually cause a problem anywhere. If you can use XSLT 2.0, you could add `copy-namespaces="no"` to the `xsl:copy` statement to remove them.

Comment: But unused namespace are required later.

Comment: If they are used later, they would not be unused, and so would not be removed.

Comment: Note that, it also doesn't matter if the namespace declarations are moved to the child elements. The XML will still be parsed correctly.